# CQRS client command management

Tags: cqrs

I'm building a new project using CQRS, It's a 3 tier application and it's expected that clients state are synchronized. The server receive commands and callback events to clients.

Currently, the model has several sub model that can be added/removed/updated, each of which has it's own command. Events are field specific i.e.

- UpdateItemCommand
- CreateSubItemCommand
- RemoveSubItemCommand
- UpdateSubItemCommand
- ...
- ItemFieldAUpdatedEvent
- SubItemFieldAUpdatedEvent
- SubItemFieldBUpdatedEvent
- ...

So here's my interrogation, the client get the current state of the model, user edit the local model, click the Save button and this is where I bug. Should I

- Compare the original state of the model (updated with received events) and the edited state of the model to generate a set of commands (on every received events it's required to identify the fields that has been updated and notify the user if he edited a field that has changed),
- Create commands as user are editing the model doing and undoing edit (that would be hard to manage),
- ...

Basically I don't know which strategy I should apply to generate the commands!

Is there an example out there, I've Google around but found noting on that subject.

Thanks,

Dominik

Comment: I recommend you to read about Task-based UI: http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/

Comment: Hi Mequrel, first of all thanks for taking the time to understand the question and give a relevant answer. This concept was unknown to me, and yes it seems to be a good solution. However, the UI design has been specified by the client and is not Task-based UI compatible. I'll try to propose this UI design to my client. I haven't though CQRS was that constraining on the UI side. Thanks again for your lights!

Comment: Hi Mequrel, could you copy paste that comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered?, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to read about [Task-based UI](http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui).